# How do I send an email notification when programatically creating a Drupal user?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to create a user using code. I have the following that created the user. It however does not send an email to the user saying that the account has been created. How can I do that?

```
$newUser = array(
  'name' => 'username',
  'pass' => 'password', // note: do not md5 the password
  'mail' => 'email address',
  'status' => 1,
  'init' => 'email address'
);           
user_save(null, $newUser);
```

Comment: Try to create user manually, Does it send an E-mail?

Comment: If I click "Notify user of new account" I do receive an email.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You could use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules). You can add an action to be fired when user is created.

Comment: Accepted answer?? What if rules isn't installed.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the standard [_user_mail_notify()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7) function from the Drupal core's "User" module.

```
   // Create user.
   $new_user = array(
      'name' => $username,
      'pass' => $password, 
      'mail' => $email,
      'status' => 1,
      'init' => $email,
      'roles' => array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE),
    );  
   $account = user_save(NULL, $new_user);
   // Set operation.
   $op = 'register_no_approval_required';
   // Send an email.
   _user_mail_notify($op, $account);
```

There are different values of $op:

```
 /* @param $op
 *   The operation being performed on the account. Possible values:
 *   - 'register_admin_created': Welcome message for user created by the admin.
 *   - 'register_no_approval_required': Welcome message when user
 *     self-registers.
 *   - 'register_pending_approval': Welcome message, user pending admin
 *     approval.
 *   - 'password_reset': Password recovery request.
 *   - 'status_activated': Account activated.
 *   - 'status_blocked': Account blocked.
 *   - 'cancel_confirm': Account cancellation request.
 *   - 'status_canceled': Account canceled.*/
```

Comment: Doesnt `_user_mail_notify` get invoked while using user_save ?? in Drupal 7 though

Answer (score 2):

Have you implemented user_register_notify? http://drupal.org/project/user_register_notify

Here are the instructions on how to set it up: http://drupal.org/node/97183/cvs-instructions/HEAD

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mimic how Drupal core handles this, take a look at [user_register_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_register_submit/6). That is the function that reacts to the checkbox you mention above, and if notifications are desired, passes the saved user object into [_user_mail_notify()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/6), which handles the sending of the message.

Answer (score 0):

implement hook_mail:

```
function YOURMODULE_mail($key, &$message, $params) {

  drupal_set_message('email test');

  switch ($key) {
    case 'mymail':
      // Set headers etc
      $message['to'] = 'youremail@email.com';
      $message['subject'] = t('Hello');
      $message['body'][] = t('Hello @username,', array('@username' => $params['username']));
      $message['body'][] = t('The main part of the message.');
      break;
}
}
```

then, use the drupal_mail() function:

```
$result = drupal_mail('example', 'mymail','email@email.com', 'en', 'params','admin@email.com', 'to@email.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers pretty much all do the same thing, but jump into the chain at different points; some requiring additional modules; and some referring to system forms.

Personally, while the Rules module can accomplish this for you, it seems a bit contradictory to programmatically create a user, then use the UI to send the notification.

I would opt for using the [_user_mail_notify()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7) method and passing the operation you want (register_pending_approval, register_no_approval_required, etc.).  This puts you in the chain low enough that you aren't relying on additional modules, but high enough that you're tapping into Drupal registration logic.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way may change your code a bit, like this (change from user_save and add the rest);

```
$account = user_save('', $newUser); //the first parameter is left blank so a new user is created

  // If you want to send the welcome email, use the following code
  // Manually set the password so it appears in the e-mail.
  $account->password = $newUser['pass'];

  // Send the e-mail through the user module.
  drupal_mail('user', 'register_no_approval_required',
    $email, NULL, array('account' => $account), variable_get('site_mail', 'noreply@yourdomain.com'));
```